# Issue with accepted Answer - points not added due to unaccept?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer, reputation-history

I answered this question here:
[Passing variables between files in WordPress or PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253543/passing-variables-between-files-in-wordpress-or-php/36254764#36254764)

The answer was upvoted and accepted but I only received 10 points. When i looked into the reputation, just before the accept is a unaccept, but the answer had not been accepted before that?

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2430392/david?tab=reputation

Anyone else had issues like this?

Comment: According to the vote history the *accept* and the *unaccept* happened at the exact same time. I smell a race condition here..

Comment: I remember that /reputation could trigger a rep recalc, now they do that every 6-8 units of time. Just allow it to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run a manual recalc of your reputation, to ensure the missing rep gets awarded (though would have happened with the scheduled job too, but why wait?).

Comment: Same issue in may case. Waited a month but it did not auto calculate.