# unaccept vs accepted - points not calculated

Tags: bug, status-norepro, accepted-answer, reputation-history

This is a duplicate of the following question: [Issue with accepted Answer - points not added due to unaccept?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320101/issue-with-accepted-answer-points-not-added-due-to-unaccept)

I had created this one to indicate my issue with a screenshot. My point did not get added after an accepted state. Waited for two weeks and no change!

See the point in question circled in read in the image bellow:

[image]

Comment: By saying it's a duplicate you mean that you have the same issue and would like someone to manually recalculate your rep?

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to ask to do the calculation without posting a question? Would like to do that in the future if the same issue happens.

Comment: You can audit your reputation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) what does that say?

Comment: Oh, the timestamps are the other way around...

Comment: How do I remove this question? It is continuously getting negative votes!

Comment: @Rahatur Since it has an upvoted answer you can't, but you should not worry about negative votes on meta, they have no impact on anything and your rep is not affected.

Answer (score 14):

You have your times mixed up. Look at the time stamps in your log:

`+15 02:25  post #1`
`-15 16:00  post #2`

One post wasn’t accepted at the start of the day. You gained 15 points when it was marked as accepted, but then lost those points again when *a different post* was unaccepted much later in the day. You never dropped reputation events here, you had 1685 points at the start of that day, went to 1700 points then dropped back to 1685.

I’m not sure how you arrived at thinking you had 1700 points by the start of this specific day, at any rate. The last reputation recalculation event logged on your account was on June 8 which confirmed you had 1515 points on that day, and you since gained 170 points before the events in your screenshot.

Comment: It seems that the question is invalid! How do we close this question?

Comment: @Rahatur: your question is not invalid, and it has already been closed, as a duplicate.

Comment: Finally! Phew... It had been gathering all -ve points. A valid question would not do that.

Comment: @Rahatur: you've misunderstood voting then, sorry. Your question is not *off topic*. People simply disagree with the assessment that you have a valid bug, that's all. Voting on Meta doesn't cost or gain you anything other than badges.